# Comparing two words in javascript not working peoperly

Tags: javascript

I want to compare two words, where for one word the letters are scrambled. It is working fine but If I add the same letters it returns true. I want the function to return false. Is there any generic method to do that. Please find my function below

```
const word1 = "apple"
const compareLetters = getWord => {
    const word1Array = word1.split('');
    const getWordArray = getWord.split('');
    return word1Array.every(word => getWordArray.includes(word))
}

compareLetters('aplep'); // -> this result gives true which is fine
compareLetters('apled'); // -> this gives false which is great
compareLetters('aplepppppppppppppppp'); // -> this give true as well. I wish to return this false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way is to sort the letters of the two strings and then do an equality check:

```js
const compareLetters = (a, b) => {
    return a.split('').sort().join('')
        === b.split('').sort().join('');
}

let compareApple = compareLetters.bind(null, "apple");

console.log(compareApple('aplep')); // true
console.log(compareApple('apled')); // false
console.log(compareApple('aplle')); // false
console.log(compareApple('aplepppppppppppppppp')); // false
```

Theoretically this is not an optimal algorithm. More optimal would be to maintain the frequency of each unique letter. But in practice that will be slower in JavaScript, except when your strings are immense long.

For completeness sake, here is a solution with *O(n)* time complexity instead of *O(nlogn)*:

```js
const compareLetters = (a, b) => {
    if (a.length !== b.length) return false;
    let map = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(a, c => [c, 0]));
    for (let c of a) map[c]++;
    for (let c of b) if (!map[c]--) return false;
    return true;
}

let compareApple = compareLetters.bind(null, "apple");

console.log(compareApple('aplep')); // true
console.log(compareApple('apled')); // false
console.log(compareApple('aplle')); // false
console.log(compareApple('aplepppppppppppppppp')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking it both ways, first with every letter of the passed word, then with every letter of  `word1` and lastly you also need to confirm that the length of the words are the same.

You can do it in the following manner -

```js
const word1 = "apple"
const compareLetters = getWord => {
  const word1Array = word1.split('');
  const getWordArray = getWord.split('');
  return word1Array.every(word => getWordArray.includes(word)) && getWordArray.every(word => word1Array.includes(word)) && word1Array.length === getWordArray.length;
}

console.log(compareLetters('aplep')); // -> this result gives true which is fine
console.log(compareLetters('apled')); // -> this gives false which is great
console.log(compareLetters('aplepppppppppppppppp')); // -> this give true as well. I wish to return this false
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below :-

```js
  
      const word1 = "apple"
      const compareLetters = getWord => {
      const word1Array = word1.split('').sort().join('');
      const getWordArray = getWord.split('').sort().join('');
      return word1Array === getWordArray;
     }

     console.log( compareLetters('aplep')); // -> this result gives true which is                                               //fine
     console.log(compareLetters('apled')); // -> this gives false which is great
     console.log(compareLetters('aplepppppppppppppppp')); // -> this give false as                                                      //well. I wish 
                                               // to  return this false`
```

Hope it will help.